# Modifying Field Values for a Custom Content Type?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I have a custom content type that has a field whose values need to be modified. The field in question is a select list and I need to add a new value to the list and re-order the list to satisfy the requirements of the project. The existing list looks like this:

```
1_Value A|Value A
2_Value B|Value B
3_Value C|Value C
```

The new list needs to look like this:

```
1_Value A|Value A
2_Value D|Value D
3_Value B|Value B
4_Value C|Value C
```

I realize because this field/content type already contains data, that this field cannot be edited. That being said, I suppose my question is two-fold:

1. How can I easily edit this field? What is the best way to export the data, make my modification and re-import?
2. Will re-ordering the values have any impact on the existing data associated with this content type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked a select list I have on a site with text key|value pairs under 'Allowed Values'. Although I had the message at the top that 'There is data for this field in the database. The field settings can no longer be changed.' I went ahead and altered the list, and it took the changes fine.

There should be no impact on the existing data if you change the order. Just be careful you never delete a value.